# Objective C - is init a bad place to implement a factory?

Tags: objective-c

I implemented the old init-as-a-factory pattern, but in one particular case (but not others!) I get a warning from the analyser regarding memory leaks. And indeed, looking at the [Cocoa Memory Management Policy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) rules, it is `alloc`, not `init`, which can return +1-retain-count objects.

So it appears that:

1. Releasing `self` and returning a new object from `init` is, strictly speaking, against the rules.
2. Many places on the internet promote this technique, and because of the tandem nature of alloc/init this does work.
3. The analyser sometimes complains about this, and sometimes doesn't.

So... have we been doing this wrong all along?

Comment: Can you post a snippet that causes the compiler error? It's a common pattern, as you point out, and it is how most class clusters are implemented.   Further, under circumstances when init can fail, the pre-arc method for dealing with failure was to dealloc self and return nil.

Comment: *Class clusters are based on the Abstract Factory design pattern.* [Concepts in Objective-C Programming: Class Clusters](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/ClassClusters/ClassClusters.html)

Answer (score 2):

you can implemented `init` like this, which should release `self` to balance the retain count from `alloc` call.

```
- (id)initWithSomething:(id)something
{
    [self release]; // don't need this line for ARC
    self = nil;
    return [[PrivateSubClass alloc] initWithSomething:something];
}
```

and it if very often to implement `init` as a factory method. e.g. `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, `NSString`

Answer (score 0):

As gaige said, it will be much more clearer if you post a piece of code rather than explanations.

Anyway, you can move your factory to the class method, so you will have no such problem at all. I mean something like this:

```
MyClass* instance = [MyClass instanceWithParameters:params];

@interface MyClass
+ (MyClass*) instanceWithParameters:(ParamType)params;
@end
```

Comment: **static** should be renamed as **class**.

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly, your code should return `MyClass *`. And its name must begin with `new` or `alloc` so that ARC knows it returns an object with +1 retain count.

Comment: And `MyClass*` would be better ;)

Comment: Class factory methods do not start with new or alloc. They normally start with their class name. For instance, stringWithFormat: in NSString, or numberWithBool: in NSNumber.

Comment: yeah, just after several months of using c# instead of objective-c forgot to add *

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what is the code that is causing the analyzer's behavior it's hard to tell, but as a general rule, here's a couple of compiler-friendly ways to define init/factory methods.

### Classic alloc/init

```
- (instancetype)initWithParameter:(id)parameter {
    if(self = [super init]) {
       _parameter = parameter; 
    }
    return self;
}
```

#### Usage

```
MyCustomClass * myInstance = [[MyCustomClass alloc] initWithParameter:foo];
```

This will produce an instance with a +1 retain count. Under ARC this will be automatically managed properly since it follows the NARC rule (New, Alloc, Retain, Copy).
For the same reason, in pre-ARC environments it has to be explicitly released by the client.

### Custom factory method

#### ARC

```
+ (instancetype)canIHazInstanceWithParameter:(id)parameter {
    return [[self alloc] initWithParameter:parameter]; // assuming -initWithParameter: defined
}
```

#### Pre-ARC

```
+ (instancetype)canIHazInstanceWithParameter:(id)parameter {
    return [[[self alloc] initWithParameter:parameter] autorelease]; // assuming -initWithParameter: defined
}
```

#### Usage

```
MyCustomClass * myInstance = [MyCustomClass canIHazInstanceWithParameter:foo];
```

Both in ARC and pre-ARC the method returns an autoreleased instance (this is clearly more explicit in the pre-ARC implementation), which doesn't have to be managed by the client.

### Remarks

- You may have noticed the `instancetype` keyword. That's a handy [language extension](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html) introduced by Clang, that turns the compiler into a dear friend when implementing your own constructors/factory methods. I wrote [an article](http://www.codepills.net/blog/2013/01/01/obj-c-infer-types-like-a-man-man/) on the subject, which may be relevant to you.
- Whether factory methods are preferable to `init` methods is debatable. From a client perspective it does not make much difference under ARC, provided that you carefully follow the naming conventions, even though I personally tend to expose factory methods in the interface, while implementing custom `init` methods only internally (as I did in the examples above). It's more a matter of style than an actual practical concern.