# Swift Objects initialization (Class factory method, default init, convenience init)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, initialization

I'm trying to figure out the best pattern to work with objects in Swift.

i think i got it right with the initializers, both convenience and default... but what happen with the class factory methods?

I tried to create a simple class Person and a subclass Student, with few properties and methods. is it the most correct way to do it?

```
   class Person{
    
    var _name: String
    var _surname: String
    var _dateOfBirthday: String
    var _phoneNumb: [String]
    
    init(name:String, surname:String, dateOfBirthday:String, phone:[String]){
        self._name = name
        self._surname = surname
        self._dateOfBirthday = dateOfBirthday
        self._phoneNumb = phone
    }
    
    convenience init() {
        self.init(name:"",surname:"",dateOfBirthday:"", phone:[])
    }
    
    convenience init(name:String){
        self.init(name:name,surname:"",dateOfBirthday:"", phone:[])
    }
    
    
}



class Student:Person{
    
    var _studentId:Int
    
    init(name: String, surname: String, dateOfBirthday: String, phone: [String], id:Int) {
        self._studentId = id
        super.init(name: "", surname: "", dateOfBirthday: "", phone: [])
    }
    
    convenience init(){
        self.init(name: "", surname: "", dateOfBirthday: "", phone: [], id:0)
    }
    
    convenience init(name:String){
        self.init(name:name,surname:"",dateOfBirthday:"", phone:[], id:0)
    }
    
}
```

what if i want to add a class factory method? would it be something like this or i'm doing it wrong?

```
class func Person() -> Person {
 var x = Person()
 x._telephoneNumber = [String]() // is this needed? or i can initialize it later?
 return x
}

class func PersonWithName(name:String) -> Person {
 var x = Person(name:name, surname:"", dateOfBirthday:"", telephoneNumber:[])
 return x
}
```

is this correct? why would it be better to use the init instead of the class factory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is this correct? why would it be better to use the init instead of the class factory?

Why would you create a "class factory" if you can use init? `init` is idiomatic Swift way of creating new objects of a class.

Adding convenience initializers is the right choice in most cases when you want to add a shortcut to class's main (designated) initializer. However, in your case, they are completely unnecessary, because Swift supports default argument values.

Just define your initializer like so:

```
init(name:String = "", surname:String = "", dateOfBirthday:String = "", phone:[String] = []) { ... }
```

This way, you can invoke it as `Person()` or `Person(name: "Andrew")` or with any other combination of arguments.

EDIT:

As a side note, prefixing instance variables with an underscore generally doesn't seem to be idiomatic Swift. It's okay to omit the underscore and use `self.` to disambiguate between local and instance variables:

```
self.name = name
self.surname = surname
self.dateOfBirthday = dateOfBirthday
self.phoneNumb = phone
```

Comment: so when would it be the case of using class factory in swift? almost never?

Comment: Yes, essentially. There might be some edge cases when it might be necessary, but I can't think of any right now. Just use init.

Comment: how about when objects are determined at runtime? Factory and Abstract Factory are a pretty standard OO design patterns. I won't even mention dependency injection and the widely used class cluster pattern. (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014122/custom-class-clusters-in-swift)

Comment: One issue with this is that calling `Person()` tells you nothing about how the object is configured. Let's say I want an initializer which sets a random age for person and therefore doesn't take a parameter. Something like `PersonWithRandomAge` in Objective-C. How would I do this in Swift?

Answer (score 0):

Prior to the recent Xcode 6.1 and Swift 1.1, it was necessary to use factory pattern if construction could fail because `init()` could not return optionals. This was also why many cocoa/objective-c libraries imported had factory methods.

With the release of Xcode 6.1 and Swift 1.1 and the support for `init()` that can return optionals, you should use the `init()` pattern with convenience initializers. With this release, Apple also changed their cocoa/objective-c imports to use the `init() -> T?` pattern over the factory method.

See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html for the release notes.

Comment: This is correct, although irrelevant in the context of OP's question where there are no failable initializers.

Comment: What do you mean with "init() that can return optionals"? I thought initializers do not return a value in swift (unlike Objective-C)

Comment: @NicolasMiari It means that "construction may fail". The reason class factories are used in some other languages is because construction cannot fail. With Swift 1.1, Apple introduced "fail-able initializers" (which are written as `init() -> T?`. This effectively means that with Swift you never need factories.

Comment: Oh, missed that one! Thanks for clarifying!